# ¿como destruir una ruta en Angular?

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Actualmente estoy practicando con un login que es como el "Home" de la aplicación y me veo en la necesidad, que cuando un usuario se identifica ya no pueda regresar al componente de login(por que ya fue verificado), y redireccionarle a su "Home" de usuario.

Para el login y restringir algunas de las rutas que tenía lo hice con

```
"CanActivate".
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{CanActivate,ActivatedRouteSnapshot,RouterStateSnapshot} from '@angular/Router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Router} from '@angular/Router';
import {UsuariosService} from './usuarios.service';
@Injectable()
export class CanActivateTeam implements CanActivate {
private activado:boolean=false;
  constructor(private _UsuariosService:UsuariosService,private _Router:Router) { }
canActivate(
    route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean> | boolean{
    this._UsuariosService.Evento.subscribe((resul)=>{
        this.activado=resul});
    if(this.activado){
return this.activado;
}else{
    this._Router.navigate(['/login']);
}      

return this.activado;

}
}
```

Pensé que borrar alguna ruta se podría hacer con "CanDeactivate" pero es solo cuando se destruye un componente.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hasta el momento? **[edit] tu pregunta** con mas detalles `código fuente, errores, etc`.

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: ya lo solucione , bueno nose si es la mejor de las opciones pero cree una variable estatica en el componente login boolean y un observable en el servicio , la cosa que cuando se "logea",el estado del usuario se guarda en la varible estatica y pregunto en el metodo de ngInit(){if(this.activado){this.route.navigate('/Home').}} y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes controlar eso con la función canActivate, comprueba que si estas logueado y la ruta nueva es el login, redireccionas a 404 o home...

También puedes hacerlo mediante el evento en el router outlet que renderiza el login, échale un ojo a este link :)

> https://netbasal.com/angular-2-router-routeroutlet-events-8b0803d88082